# Swift -How to get movie file outputFileURL before or while app goes to/in background

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

The problem I have is if the camera is recording, when the app has either entered the bg or is about to enter the bg, I stop recording but the `outputFileURL` is never saved. I always get an error of `"Recording Stopped"`. I **individually** tried to stop the recording using all 3 of the Notification methods below but nada.

```
let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

@objc func appWillEnterBackground() { // UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification triggers this

    if movieFileOutput.isRecording {
        movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
    }
}

@objc func didEnterBackground() { // UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification triggers this

    if movieFileOutput.isRecording {
       movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
    }
}

@objc func sessionWasInterrupted(notification: NSNotification) { // .AVCaptureSessionWasInterrupted triggers this

    // ...
    let reason = AVCaptureSession.InterruptionReason(rawValue: reasonIntegerValue) {
        
     switch reason {
        
     case .videoDeviceNotAvailableInBackground:

         DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

             if self!.movieFileOutput.isRecording {
                self!.movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
             }
         }
     }
}

func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    if error == nil {

        let asset = AVAsset(url: outputFileURL)
        self.arrayVideos.append(asset)

    } else {

       print(error!.localizedDescription) // prints "Recording Stopped"
    }
}
```

Just to be clear, I do not want to record while in the background. I want to get the `outputFileURL` after `movieFileOutput.stopRecording()` is triggered while the app is either on its way to the bg or has entered the bg.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, so I'll post it here.

I tested this on iOS 13.5.1, it seems to stop recording automatically when App goes to background and the video is saved.

The following is the code I used to test:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var movieFileOutput: AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        startCapturing()
    }

    func startCapturing() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
        let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)
        guard let captureDevice = discoverySession.devices.first else {
            print("Failed to discovert session")
            return
        }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {
            print("Failed to create capture device input")
            return
        }
        captureSession.addInput(input)

        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = contentView.bounds
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func startRecording() {
        if self.movieFileOutput == nil {
            let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
            if let connection = movieFileOutput.connection(with: .video) {
                movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecType.h264], for: connection)
            }
            captureSession.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
            if let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
                let outputUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent("out.mp4")
                movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: outputUrl, recordingDelegate: self)
            }
            self.movieFileOutput = movieFileOutput
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        if let movieFileOutput = self.movieFileOutput {
            movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
            captureSession.removeOutput(movieFileOutput)
            self.movieFileOutput = nil
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onStartClick(_ sender: Any) {
        startRecording()
        
    }

    @IBAction func onStopClick(_ sender: Any) {
        stopRecording()
    }

}

extension ViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
        print("File saved to: \(outputFileURL), error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem with your method is that the file isn't being saved inside the `fileOutput` delegate method, that is where all of my assets are saved. It seems your your url is being saved via `movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: outputUrl, recordingDelegate: self)`, I have to rearrange a ton of code. I need the the outputFile to be saved via the `fileOutput` delegate method.

Comment: @LanceSamaria, I tested it again, and printed the output in the `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate`, and this is true:
` FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputFileURL.path)`

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. Right now I’m working right on another bug. I’ll get back to this by tomorrow or Tuesday and I’ll message you

Comment: Btw, I never said your code didn’t work. My setup movieFile.startRecording... I have to figure out how to use that method and set it to save the url to the asset. It seems I would have to move all of my logic from the fileOutput delegate method to your method.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, so the following might not be true for your case. If what you need is to keep the 'save to file' logic in the delegate, why not just call startRecording with a temp URL (like cache directory), then in your delegate, move that file to your destination?

Comment: I never used that startRecording function before. I have to think this through. I can make a github repo with my current if you want to take a look at it